# Securing REST Jersey

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jersey

I'm trying to secure a Jersey service on Tomcat and I have a problem accessing it from a browser. I have tried several tutorials but no one has a correct solution, so if you had yet worked with REST, please tell me where the problem is. Here are the config files I am using:

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security for Your Enterprise</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Your Enterprise web Security</web-resource-name>
        <description>Redirect all to SSL</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description />
        <role-name>role1</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>Protection should be CONFIDENTIAL</description>
        <transport-guarantee>INTEGRAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
```

sever.xml of tomcat

```
<Connector
    clientAuth="false"
    minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200"
    port="8443"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="serverkey.keystore"
    keystorePass="pwd"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
```

tomcat-users :

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <user
        username="CN=10.0.25.21,OU=, O=, L=, ST=, C="
        password="pwd" roles="role1"
    />
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you asking for?

Comment: I tried to secure REST Jersey with SSL but il doesn't work, I made all changes in files configuration, so if you know the steps please help me, I posted my files configurartion

Comment: So you want to secure your restful website with ssl? As in have requests to your website go over https? (Just trying to make sure I understand you before I give an answer :))

Comment: Yes, thank you, I used SSL that implements HTTPS, so I created the pair Keys client and server and I can deploy the webservice in the browser with https url, but when I try to access to some resources of the web service e.g (https://localhost:8443/WebService/book, it doesn't give me a result, while when I try with only http it works

Comment: Please I have always the same problem, can any one who know the solution to tell how to resolve the problem or to tell me the steps to make it works thanks

Comment: Have you created an ssl cetificate and added it to your tomcat instance?

Comment: Yes, I create the certificat for both server and client, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Are you connecting over port 8443?

Comment: yes, I tried but always the  same problem

Comment: I think I'm out of ideas :P The best I can do is to direct you to the doc: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/ssl-howto.html and hope that someone else comes along and is able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change  value to CONFIDENTIAL.